# Split ByteArray into chunks of size 1024bytes(each chunk should be byteArray) , merge all Chunks into ByteArray again in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-bluetooth, file-sharing

How to split a ByteArray into chunks of byteArray in java, each chunk has a size of 1024 byte or less, then a method to collect each chunk into Bytearray.
I'm working with offline File sharing via BlueTooth. The main goal is to share a large size Hashmap to another device via I/O streams using Bluetooth Sockets.
It would be a great favor if anyone responds with an example java code for both methods.

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream out = null;
mapDatabyte = null;
try {
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    out.writeObject(mapVideoData);
    out.flush();
    mapDatabyte = bos.toByteArray();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

} finally {
    try {
        bos.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //...
    } 
}
```

Comment: How does one put a hashmap in a byte array?

Comment: If you share a file you do not need a big byte array which you would then send in chuncks. There are better approaches.

Comment: @blackapps can you please describe better approaches as compared to mentioned above, Thanks!

Comment: convert whole hashmap into bytearray.  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        mapDatabyte = null;
        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            out.writeObject(mapVideoData);
            out.flush();
            mapDatabyte = bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                bos.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
              
            }
        }

Comment: Put your code in your post to make it readable. Remove that comment.